# how to validate dynamic field array laravel 5.6 with required_with_all?

Tags: arrays, validation, laravel-5, dynamic

i have 3 inputs fields i want validation in such a style that if any field (out of 3)is filled then all three are required if none of them is filled then nothing require please tell me the solution in laravel 5.6.

Note:These 3 inputs fields are array.If someone click on add more button this fields will be increment.

I tried required_with and required_with all but nothing gain.i saw another posts not solved my problem.

My View:

```
<div class="box_general padding_bottom">
        <div class="header_box version_2">
            <h2><i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i>Special&nbsp;/&nbsp;Holiday Hours</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <table id="pricing-list-container" style="width:100%;">
                    <tbody><tr class="pricing-list-item">
                        <td>
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-md-4">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Title" name="holidays_title[]" id="holidays_title[]" >
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-3">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="time" class="form-control" name="opening_holidays_hours[]"  id="opening_holidays_hours[]">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="time" name="closing_holidays_hours[]"  class="form-control" id="closing_holidays_hours[]">
                </div>
            </div>
                                <div class="col-md-2">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <a class="delete" href="#"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-remove"></i></a>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody></table>
                <a href="#0" class="btn_1 gray add-pricing-list-item"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-plus-circle"></i>Add Item</a>
                </div>
        </div>
```

**My Controller**

```
public function createStore(Request $request)
{   


    $request->validate([

       'holidays_title'   => 'array|min:1|required_with_all:opening_holidays_hours,closing_holidays_hours',
         'opening_holidays_hours' => 'required_with_all:holidays_title,closing_holidays_hours',
         'closing_holidays_hours' => 'required_with_all:holidays_title,opening_holidays_hours',


    ]);

    return redirect()->back();
}
```

**Expected:**
I just want if any one out of 3 is filled then two others fields must be required.If none of them is filled then no required.

**Actual Result:**
but now no errors are showing me in my view if i filled the title field and submit the form

Answer (score 0):

Try like this.

**If statement** should be your solution :)
for example...

**In your controller**

```
public function createStore(Request $request)
{   

    $validator = $request->validate([
                    'holidays_title' => 'required'
                 ]);

    if ($request->holidays_title != null) {
       return redirect()->back()->withErrors($validator);
    }
    elseif($request->opening_holidays_hours != null && $request->closing_holidays_hours != null) {
       $validator = $request->validate([
                            'holidays_title' => 'required',
                            'opening_holidays_hours' => 'required',
                            'closing_holidays_hours' => 'required'
                            ]);
    }
    else($request == null){
      return redirect()->back();
    }

    return redirect()->back()->withErrors($validator);
}
```

and also have to insert `flash::message` in your Blade file.https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/validation#manually-creating-validators

Comment: error is  not showing the form is validated as i don't want..if i filled title field and left the other two blank the form is successfully validated i want it should show me the error to fill other fills too.@Magnetic

Comment: please help me i am trapped in this problem since one day.

Comment: check edited answer. and why did you made all valiables as array type?

Comment: because i want dynamically add fields..have you seen my question please?